# PrimeNG Chips: edit chip with select list

Tags: angular, primeng

I would like to make such thing with PrimeNG Chips: when clicking on a Chip, it changes to a select list with available values. Choosing one of the select list items causes a change of the clicked chip value:

1. [image]
2. When clicking on `Value1`

   [image]
3. After selecting `New York`

   [image]

How could such a component be created?

Answer (score 0):

your desired component may be already part of primeng suite:

[MultiSelect Chips](https://primeng.org/multiselect#chips)